# Text moves when hovering button

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material to build an application. I want to use `mat-stroked-button`, but I have encountered a problem. As you can see in the gif below, whenever I hover the button all text quickly moves down and then back up. I can't figure out why this is happening.

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="home">
  <div id="side">
    <div id="info">
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      Info here
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
      <button mat-stroked-button *ngFor="let item of menuItems">{{item}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <button mat-stroked-button>BUTTON</button>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.css:

```
#home{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 99%;
    height: 98%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
#side{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}
#info{
    background: brown;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#navigation{
    background: brown;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#info h1 {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
}
button[mat-stroked-button]{
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

styles.css:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

body, html, #home{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
```

I have replicated the problem on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfbd5v

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see your css?

Comment: @EmandM Added all CSS.

Comment: There is no way to replicate this. I have tried CodePen and loaded angular-material, but it works just fine in 3 different browsers (Safari, Chrome and Firefox). It could be a gazillion different things and it could be something simple and trivial. Try to find a way to provide more code or give us access to the code somewhere or - even better - jump in your dev tools and watch the css on that button (compare computed values) for "normal" button and for "hovered" button. 
You actually learn the most by debugging your code and not giving up.

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac I have been trying to look through DevTools but I've run out of ideas. I've replicated the problem on stackblitz. You can find the link in my post. Thank you.

Comment: @Jesper - again, everything works fine on different browsers for me. Here's FF (https://gyazo.com/4493c448e0a19143e5a9faee387320e9), Chrome (https://gyazo.com/54b222b5a5a07427a620c74beb607001) and Safari (https://gyazo.com/07af2cb3bba539ed5436b073d0c93453). Which browser are you using and have you tried a different one?

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac That is indeed very odd. I am using Chrome Version 70.0.3538.77. I just tested it in Internet Explorer and there are no problems there..

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac Pretty sure that the OP is referring to the newer Angular Material framework, instead of the former AngularJS 1.x Material framework. CodePen doesn't support Angular projects in the first place. Could you clarify your second sentence?

Answer (score 1):

In `app/appcomponent.css`, remove the `translate` properties, and try the below code. It will stop the elements from jumping about.

```
#home{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 2%;
  left: 2%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The only problem is that I wanted there to be whitespace all the way around the edge, which is no longer there when i remove width and height. Any suggestion as to how I can keep the whitespace?

Comment: @Jester - set the desired padding value to `#home`'s parent - I guess it's body.

Comment: @Jesper Try the above code. Takes care of the jumping, and the whitespace. Feel free to tweak values as you need.

Comment: @Jester - because you have set `#home` to `position: absolute` and removed it from the flow. Why on earth did you need to do that and to give yourself a headache of writing next 8 lines of code in order to "center" it - I have no idea. But, now it's obvious that you have some serious problems with some VERY basic (understanding of) CSS. I would suggest that you get familiar with the basic concepts before you continue with this project. Otherwise, you'll go down the rabbit hole and ask here on SO for every new "bug" and there will be plenty.

Comment: I agree with @NemanjaGlumac, using absolute positioning on the top-most div is a bad idea, and you’ll run into position dependencies for all elements that follow. That said, maybe Jesper is just trying to learn, and this is how you learn— by doing shit that obviously breaks. That’s how coding works, and there’s nothing wrong with getting on SO every time you have a question. That rabbit-hole is the best way to learn, IMHO.

Comment: Yup, but only if you break it and then debug it yourself, while learning in the process. Because, in order to debug something, you HAVE TO learn. Getting answers on SO is great in many cases, but if you don't understand the underlying concepts (such as margin vs. padding) it's not going to help you. You'll copy and paste the code and it will work, but you will still NOT know why it works. And that's very very misleading and dangerous.

Comment: Agreed. Copy-pasting solves only half the problem...I used to do that in the beginning too. :)

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac I do have a basic understanding of CSS, but it has been some time since I worked with it so there are some things I need refreshed. The reason why I did `position: absolute;` to center it is that I couldn't find any other way to create the whitespace/border around the whole thing. If you have another suggestion, I would love to hear it.

Comment: @Jesper - "Whitespace" you are constantly referring to is usually achieved using `margin` (you can set it to child) or `padding` (set it to parent). Btw, the simplest possible (horizontal) centering of the element is done via margins (again, in your case: `#home {margin: 0 auto;}`).

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac It doesn't seem like it's as simple as using margin or padding (I've tried). `margin: 10px`,  `padding: 10px` and  `border: 10px solid white` all result in the same thing, which is a border/whitespace on the top and left, but not on the bottom and right.

Comment: It is as simple as that (when you know what you're doing and when you don't create spaghetti from the very beginning). I'm sorry but I'm out. Good luck.

Comment: @Jesper So what did you finally use?

Comment: @SujanSundareswaran I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: @Jesper - oh man, I can't believe this... like I said: it really, really, REALLY is that simple, but with huge IF - if you don't write the code you don't understand. So, from a "strange button behaviour" now we've come to rewriting your whole CSS. Here, hope this will end this conversation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kh7cf1.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your override styles for the button to hover as well

```
button[mat-stroked-button], button[mat-stroked-button]:hover {
```

Comment: Put the override after the theme input

Comment: Put the theme import before all of your CSS

Comment: It already is at the top - the CSS from the import is from `styles.css`. I updated my post to make it clear.